# Generate HTML from Spreadsheet passed as variable

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to serve HTML as a web app and pass a specific spreadsheet id every time it is accessed to see spreadsheet specific data? I have a collection of spreadsheets in the same data format only with different data values owned by many people. What I want to achieve is giving them an option to view their data in predefined html format, allowing only users with spreadsheet access to view the data.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  The published URL of the Web App can take search string parameters.  A Web App already uses the `doGet()` function, you will need to add a parameter: `doGet(e)`  Typically, the documentation uses the letter `e` as the parameter, but the name can be anything.  See the following [Link to Apps Script documentation - URL Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters)

Comment: Here is a shared Apps Script file with an example template of a Web App that will process an `id` parameter in the search string of the URL.  [Link to my Apps Script file as a Web App](https://script.google.com/d/1U6eEQkgMxcD5woPU6urj2E_shZp2DcCgl49NTMZkk2TAz7x-BZBVmb-b/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is awesome, Sandy! Really appreciate it. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search string will need to be added to the end of the published URL of the Web App:

> script.google.com/macros/s/FILE_ID_Here/exec?id=12345678

The search string part is:  `?id=12345678`

The `doGet(e)` function can get the search string as an object by using the `parameter` or `parameters` property of the object.  This example shows how to get the `id` from the search string.

```
var EXAMPLE_OF_GLOBAL_VARIABLE;//Put global variables in all CAPS

function doGet(e) {
  var searchStringAsObject,spreadsheetID,template;

  searchStringAsObject = e.parameters;//Get the search string that was appended to the URL of this published Web App as an object
  Logger.log('searchStringAsObject: ' + JSON.stringify(searchStringAsObject))

  spreadsheetID = searchStringAsObject.id;//For this to work- the search string must look like this:  urlHere?id=1234567
  //For example:
  //script.google.com/macros/s/FILE_ID_Here/exec?id=12345678

  Logger.log('spreadsheetID: ' + spreadsheetID)

  if (spreadsheetID) {
    EXAMPLE_OF_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "The spreadsheet ID is: " + spreadsheetID;
  }

  template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
};
```

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
    This is a heading
    <br>
    <br>
    <?= EXAMPLE_OF_GLOBAL_VARIABLE || "No Data"?>
  </body>
</html>
```